# Trying to make a sortable column in Wordpress to report the number of words in a post

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I am trying to make a sortable column in Wordpress to report the number of words in a post. The code successfully. Can you tell me what is wrong with this code?

```
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'add_my_column');

function add_my_column($wordcount_column) {
    $wordcount_column['wordcount_column'] = 'Words';
    return $wordcount_column;
}

//Link the word count to our new column//
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column',  'display_wordcount'); 

function display_wordcount($name) 
{
   global $post;
   switch ($name)
{
     case 'wordcount_column':
        //Get the post ID and pass it into the get_wordcount function//
        $wordcount_column = get_wordcount($post->ID);
        echo $wordcount_column;
     }
}

function get_wordcount($post_id) {
     //Get the post, remove any unnecessary tags and then perform the word count// 
     $wordcount_column = str_word_count( strip_tags( get_post_field( 'post_content', $post_id ) ) );
     return $wordcount_column;
}

function register_sortable_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['wordcount_column'] = 'Words';
    return $columns;
}

add_filter( 'manage_edit-post_sortable_columns', 'register_sortable_columns' );

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_wordcount_column_orderby' );

function my_wordcount_column_orderby( $query ) {
    $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby');
    if( 'wordcount_column' == $orderby ) {
        $query->set('meta_key','wordcount_column');
        $query->set('orderby','meta_value_num');
    }
}
```

Thanks Mel

The words display correctly, but when I click the column then the sorting seems to be random.

Comment: do you have any function to update the word count in meta value?

Comment: I don’t have anything else other than the code I included. Is there a missing function or array I need to add?

Comment: Yes, you have to add some more codes

Answer (score 0):

add these code at the bottom.

```
/**
 * Save post word count to a custom field.
 */
function wp98_save_post_word_count( $post_id ) {
    if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) && ! wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ) ) {
        $content = get_post_field( 'post_content', $post_id );
        $word_count = str_word_count( strip_tags( $content ) );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'wordcount_column', $word_count );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'wp98_save_post_word_count' );
```

after adding this code you have to open every post edit page and update them. let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: I knew I forgot something update_post_meta! Thanks again for your help, Mel